# How to create worker with elm 0.17

Tags: node.js, ports, elm

For elm 0.16, I just defined some ports
 (that are just `Signal` of data) without main function and
used `Signal.map` to process data back and forth.
It is just for data processing called from nodejs (not from browser),
 so I do not depend on `Html` module.

Now elm 0.17 has `Cmd` and `Sub` instead of `Signal`,
I cannot figure out how to do the same...

Can anybody give me an simplest example to do data
processing via ports exposed by `worker` initialization
 with elm 0.17?

---

Here is my simplest example with Elm 0.16...

**elm 0.16 code:**

```
module Main where
import Signal
import String exposing (isEmpty, reverse)

-- input ports
port jsToElm : Signal String

-- output ports
port elmToJs : Signal String
port elmToJs
  = Signal.map String.reverse jsToElm
```

**javascript (es6) code:**

```js
/** main */
const Elm = loadElm('./index.js') // custom function to eval Elm code
const app = Elm.worker( Elm.Main, { jsToElm: ''})

app.ports.jsToElm.send('test')

app.ports.elmToJs.subscribe(( txt ) => {    
    console.log( txt )
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

There is now a package that gives you the ability to create a worker. See [lukewestby/worker](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/lukewestby/worker/2.0.0/)

**Original Answer**

I was able to get a working example by creating an Html.App program. I can't find any way around the requirement of having a `main` function that results in a program that includes a `view` function, and [I'm not alone in that confusion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/elm-discuss/worker/elm-discuss/FdmuPgEXXBo/ibqHEqikCQAJ).

My example here is browser based, hopefully this fits back into your node-based version; I just haven't used the node version before.

**Main.elm**:

```elm
port module Main exposing (..)

import Json.Decode
import Json.Encode
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.App

import String exposing (isEmpty, reverse)

-- input ports
port jsToElm : (String -> msg) -> Sub msg

-- output ports
port elmToJs : String -> Cmd msg

type alias Flags = { jsToElm : String }

main =
  Html.App.programWithFlags
    { init = init
    , view = view
    , update = update
    , subscriptions = subscriptions
    }

type alias Model = { text : String }

init : Flags -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
init flags =
  (Model flags.jsToElm, Cmd.none)

type Msg
  = Reverse String

update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
  case msg of
    Reverse str ->
      let reversed = reverse str
      in ({ model | text = reversed }, elmToJs reversed)

view : Model -> Html.Html Msg
view model =
  text <| "text is: " ++ model.text

subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions _ =
  jsToElm Reverse
```

**index.html**:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="Main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = Elm.Main.fullscreen({
  jsToElm: 'first'
});

window.setTimeout(function() {
  app.ports.jsToElm.send('test');
}, 1);

app.ports.elmToJs.subscribe(function ( txt ) {    
    console.log( txt )
});
</script>
```

A couple takeaways:

1. As you can see, the simple mapping of Signals is gone and there is much more boilerplate for such a small example. The idea is that you set up your subscription to the port, then send a Cmd inside the `update` function when you want to send information back to Javascript.
2. This whole Cmd/Sub thing requires a [`Program`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.0/Platform) and the only way to do that (that I could find) was to include [`Html.App`]. I have a hunch that in the future, the core `Router` type can be used to make a "headless" worker, but it seems like for now we're stuck with requiring the Html.App program and having to render a view.
3. You'll notice the `setTimeout` call when sending `"test"` to the port in javascript. I'm not sure *why* this kludge is necessary but [others have seen it before as well](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/elm-discuss/worker/elm-discuss/FdmuPgEXXBo/ibqHEqikCQAJ)

Comment: Thank you for the help.  It is sad to see that we have to use the ugly work around now.  I hope it will get fixed.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The [upgrade guide](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-platform/blob/master/upgrade-docs/0.17.md#upgrading-ports) goes into this, but I'll summarize here with references to your code:

**Input Port:**

```
-- 0.16
port jsToElm : Signal String

-- 0.17
port jsToElm : (String -> msg) -> Sub msg
```

**Output Port:**

```
-- 0.16
port elmToJs : Signal String

-- 0.17
port elmToJs : String -> Cmd msg
```

The [new Elm guide](http://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/javascript.html) explains exactly how to hook all of this up.

Comment: How do I connect input port into output port (in Elm 0.16, I use `Signal.map` to directly connect them)?  The example given in migration guide uses `Html.App` which I do not have or need.

Comment: @Tosh: Honestly, I'm not sure. The documentation for people who aren't using `Html.App` seems really weirdly limited in the new guide.

Comment: Thank you very much for the update anyway... At least, I know that I'm not the only one who cannot find information outside of `Html.App` usage.  I'll wait for other suggestions.